# Generate jar containing .java files from protobuf using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am using the [protoc-jar-maven-plugin](https://os72.github.io/protoc-jar-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) to automatically generate Java classes out of my .proto files (via this Maven plugin). While the documentation of the plugin says that a jar file containing the classes can be generated, I couldn't find the configuration to achieve that.
My code below creates the Java classes correctly under target/generated-sources, but does not wrap them into a jar archive.
My relevant pom.xml snippet:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.os72}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>protoc.main</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <protocVersion>${version.protobuf}</protocVersion>
                            <addSources>main</addSources>
                            <inputDirectories>
                                <include>src/main/resources/protobuf</include>
                            </inputDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Do you know how can I obtain a jar file under generated-sources? (Or any other place, doesn't matter.)

Comment: Generated source should be compiled like any other sources - how did you invoke maven?

Comment: I ran it with ```mvn clean install``` and was expecting to see a .jar file somewhere.